# SQL Replace all integers in a column with another integer

Tags: sql

Looking for a way to replace all instances of 4 in column UserIDFS with 5 in this table. The UserIDFS column is an integer data type. What is the best way to do this?

[image]

Comment: `UPDATE tablename SET UserIDFS = 5 WHERE UserIDFS = 4`. You should find a good SQL tutorial or book - this is a very basic question.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE tablename

SET UserIDFS = REPLACE(CAST(UserIDFS as nvarchar(5)),'4','5')

WHERE UserIDFS = 4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).